# How can I change the image of a button when tapping on another button in another tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITabBarController` which has 3 tabs (tab1 ,tab2 ,tab3). Each tab has 1 UITableView, and each table view has a button in each row. Now I want the user to click on any button on tab2, and button in tab1 should have changed images. I can get tag of button in tab1 but I don't know how to get tag of button in tab1 when click on button in tab2. How can i do that?

Thanks a lot.

This is my code create tableview in tab1:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *market= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];

        market.tag = 4000;
        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];

        UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 30)];
        pricelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        pricelabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        pricelabel.tag = 3000;
        pricelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
        [pricelabel release];
    }

    UIButton *marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];

    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    if([sellingArray count]>0)
    {
        if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
        {
            [marketButton setSelected:NO];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;
        }
        else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
        {
            [marketButton setSelected:YES];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;
        }
    }

    [market setTag:indexPath.row];

    if([priceNewArray count]> 0)
    {
        UILabel *pricelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];

        pricelbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[priceNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        if ([sellingArray count]>0)
        {
            if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])
            {
                pricelbl.hidden = NO;
            }
            else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                pricelbl.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I tried use [tableview reloadData] but it only reloads UILabel, UIButton is not changing the image when I compare them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for calling other class Method from current class like bellow example:-

add Notification at MainClass in your `ViewDidLoad` Method:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(UpdateBtn:)
                                                 name:@"updateBtn"
                                               object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)UpdateBtn:(NSNotification *)notification {

   //Update your button image code here
}
```

Now you just need to call this method From your `popupView` class Button click Action for calling update Notification

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateBtn" object:self];
```

Hope it's Helps you:)

Comment: If i want to send string from tab2 to tab1? how can i do it? thanks

Comment: Use one Globle string Variable with property and sythsize that create in to Your Appdeleate class and help with object of appdelegate you can use this anyware of project

Comment: thanks but it still has issue, when i click on button in Tab2, i can get key, then i need send this key to tab1, how can do that?

Comment: objappdelegate.strVariable=@"Key"; and use this in second tab method [lblVariable setText:Objappdelgate.strVariable];

Comment: Yes, i did pass string but now i don't know how to get which button1 on uitableview? I knew IndexPath.row of uitableview but i don't know to detect which button1. Because in each row has 2 button