# Performing method on another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using following code to set the text of a **UILabel** in **SViewController**, From another ViewController **FViewController**

```
SViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SViewController"];
[vc setTextForLabel:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The setTextForLabel method:

```
-(void) setTextForLabel: (NSNumber *)text {
      textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
      [textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[text stringValue]]];
      NSLog(@"The text is %@", textLabel.text);
}
```

I have declared the property for textLabel in **.h file** is as follows:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;`
And I have also set the IBOutlet in storyboard.

Now in console I see "The text is 1", but the UI is not showing anything!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: take a look u can use NSNoticiatonCenter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352043/how-can-i-change-the-image-of-a-button-when-tapping-on-another-button-in-another/18352112#18352112

Comment: `textLabel` is `IBOutlet`, do not allocate it again.

Comment: I think there is something wrong if you need to call a method in another view controller, other than via a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

Also, you need to link the UILabel on interface to your @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

Or you may add this label manually to view
     textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     [textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[text stringValue]]];

```
 [self.view addSubView:textLabel];
```

Comment: If I remove alloc and init it displays (null) instead of 1, cause (apparently?) instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier doesn't call [[SViewController alloc] init]. +If I try to put the label programmatically on screen it won't show.

Comment: (null) is because your variable UILabel does not linked to real label on screen. Try to create a label with frame and add it to view UILabel *lblH2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 60)];  lblH2.text = @"test";  [self.view addSubView:lblH2];

Comment: lblH2 shows, I wil try checking again the whole code for stupid mistakes :/

Comment: UILabel *showText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(176, 131, 124, 58)];
    showText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[text stringValue]];
    [self.view addSubview:showText];
    NSLog(@"The text is %@", showText.text); Works and shows

Comment: Good. Mark as answer please

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
#import "FViewController.h"
#import "SViewController.h"
@interface FViewController ()

@end

@implementation FViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)do:(id)sender
{
    SViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
     [vc setTextForLabel:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}

// in SViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
-(void) setTextForLabel: (NSNumber *)text;
@end


 // SViewController.m file
#import "SViewController.h"

@interface SViewController ()

@end


@implementation SViewController
@synthesize label;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) setTextForLabel: (NSNumber *)text{
 //   label.text = [text stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
    [label setText:[text stringValue]];
}

@end
```

[image: Storyboard]

also check your label properties in storyboard are properly set

Comment: textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; //comment this line

Comment: Is this working for you? Even after pushViewController this isn't working... Guess I have some problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is linked to the view lifecycle of SViewController. When you call `[.. setTextForLabel]` you don't know if the controller has loaded its views (And thus your UILabel have a good chance of not being created yet)

What you should do is use a NSString property on your controller, set it with the desire text and assigned it to the UILabel in the viewDidLoad of SViewController.

in SViewController.h

```
@propery (strong, nonatomic) NSString *textToDisplay;
```

in SViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Here you know all Outlet are loaded and connected
    textLabel.text = textToDisplay
}
```

Comment: viewDidAppear ... not viewDidLoad ... since viewDidAppear is called after loading the.xib while didLoad before ... so it will keep the value for the UILabel from the .xib (see my response bellow)

Comment: viewDidLoad is called after the main view is loaded from the NIB. In the code snippet above, having the set in didLoad or didAppear will have the same effect

Answer (score 0):

First of all go put

```
[vc setTextForLabel:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

after you push the vc.

In your xib/storyboard if your label has something written in it, remove it, leave it blank. 
If that doesn't work ... leave the setText method before the push one (as you wrote it initialy) and create a NSNumber member that will hold your value and apply it in viewDidAppear like so

```
-(void) setTextForLabel: (NSNumber *)text{
numberValue = text;  // declared in .h as NSNumber *numberValue (only make it a property if you need acces to it from outside your class)
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated]; //this is important
[textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[numberValue stringValue]]];
}
```